# Suggested setup for OS project with several NuGet packages

Tags: c#, github, continuous-integration, nuget, appveyor

I decided to share a small project I have been working on for a while. It's basically a development framework for distributed applications.

Now I'm setting up the GitHub repository and I wanted to use AppVeyor for continuous integration and I'm struggling with the setup.

As for now, my framework is composed of few packages

- **Interfaces**: defines the basic interfaces, extracted as a package so that you don't need to bring the whole framework in your business logic library
- **Core**: contains the basic components of the framework
- **CastleWindsor**: contains support for the Castle IoC container
- **RabbitMQ**: contains the implementation of the engine based on RabbitMQ

Now, it's pretty easy to setup AppVeyor to build and push into Nuget a single project/package.

But what I'm looking is:

- build everything on push (includes testing)
- create packages and publish them only on a specific action.

I'm wondering if I should create multiple repositories (one for each package) on GitHub and have multiple projects on AppVeyor as well. Or maybe a single repository with multiple projects.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: question: your visual studio solution has a few projects in it ... and it finally creates some nuget packages ... and you want these MULTIPLE packages to be pushed up to NuGet or MyGet ?

Comment: Technically I was thinking about having multiple solutions. Each solution will result in a package. I might have a single solution but since projects wouldn't be referencing each other directly, there is no use for that.

Comment: AppVeyor handles a single solution _per build_. And the built in *publish to NuGet* has a very strict convention to do 1x package for 1x solution. So would this be what you're after?

Comment: For comparison, I have a single solution with multiple projects. I then have _multiple_ `.nuspec` files (one per project). I then get AV to pack and publish _all_ the `nupkg`'s that are created. I can help you with this, if you want.

Comment: @Pure.Krome thanks. I eventually solved it by making sure that AV uses IncludeReferencedProjects when invoking nuget pack.